# How to enlarge/move polygon in Java?

Tags: java, polygon

So I have the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Triangle extends Point {
    protected int size;
    private int p1x, p2x, p3x, p1y, p2y, p3y;

    //Create a new triangle
    public Triangle()
    {
        super();
        size = 100;
        yPos = 100;
    }


    public void reSize(int newSize) {
        size = size + newSize;
    }

    //Draw the triangle with current specifications on screen.
    public void display(Graphics g) {
        p1x = (size / 3);
        p2x = (size / 2);
        p3x = ((2 * size) / 3);
        p1y = ((2 * size) / 3);
        p2y = (size / 3);
        p3y = ((2 * size) / 3);
        int[] xPoints = { p1x, p2x, p3x };
        int[] yPoints = { p1y, p2y, p3y };
        int npoints = 3;
        g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, npoints);
    }
}
```

And the following code is used to enlarge/reduce the triangle:

```
    if (e.getSource() == makeBigger) {
          aShape.reSize(20);
    }

    else if (e.getSource() == makeSmaller) {
          aShape.reSize(-20);
    }
```

The problem is, I also want the ability to drag it using the following code:

```
    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        shapeColor = Color.black;
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        shapeColor = Color.lightGray;
        aShape.moveXY(me.getX(), me.getY());
        repaint();
    }
});

    this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
        shapeColor = Color.black;
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        shapeColor = Color.lightGray;
        aShape.moveXY(me.getX(), me.getY());
        repaint();
    }
});
```

And the only way I can see it is that I can have either one or the other. How do I combine it so I can have both features? At the moment it resizes perfectly, but say I change the variablle size in the x/y coordinates to yPos/xPos I'll be able to drag the triangle but not reshape it.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks to me like you want to add offsets to the `xPoints` and `yPoints` variables: `int[] xPointsMoved = {p1x + xOffset, p2x + xOffset, p3x + xOffset}` and likewise for the y dimension.

Comment: By the way, you may want to declare `p1x, p2x, p3x, p1y, p2y, p3y` inside the `display` method, since that's the only place where they are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add `xOffset` and `yOffset` members and add those in when calculating the corner points:

```
public class Triangle extends Point {
    protected int size;
    private int p1x, p2x, p3x, p1y, p2y, p3y;
    private int xOffset=0;
    private int yOffset=0;

    // ...

    //Draw the triangle with current specifications on screen.
    public void display(Graphics g) {
        p1x = (size / 3) + xOffset;
        p2x = (size / 2) + xOffset;
        p3x = ((2 * size) / 3) + xOffset;
        p1y = ((2 * size) / 3) + yOffset;
        p2y = (size / 3) + yOffset;
        p3y = ((2 * size) / 3) + yOffset;
        int[] xPoints = { p1x, p2x, p3x };
        int[] yPoints = { p1y, p2y, p3y };
        int npoints = 3;
        g.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, npoints);
    }

    public void moveXY(int deltaX, int deltaY) {
        xOffset += deltaX;
        yOffset += deltaY;
    }
}
```

This should let you translate the polygon. Note however that the `moveXY` method stated above expects parameters containing the *difference* from earlier, not an absolute position. If you want an absolute position instead, that's easy to achieve and left as an exercise. ;)